# An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, liquibase

Please, can someone help? I am trying to run the application but it keeps getting this error. Did someone have a similar problem? Running gradle app

```
2019-01-07 23:29:19.827  WARN 4450 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/wikbit/configuration/LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
2019-01-07 23:29:19.844  INFO 4450 --- [           main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  : Stopped o.s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@864d4d{/,file:/tmp/jetty-docbase.1621285029316441126.8080/,UNAVAILABLE}
2019-01-07 23:29:19.856 ERROR 4450 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/wikbit/configuration/LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.wikbit.BachelorThesisApplication.main(BachelorThesisApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:390) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:77) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:687) ~[c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar:0.9.2.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140) ~[c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar:0.9.2.1]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:385) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:na]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@1d389f2 -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1416) ~[c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar:0.9.2.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:606) ~[c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar:0.9.2.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:526) ~[c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar:0.9.2.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:755) ~[c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar:0.9.2.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:682) ~[c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar:0.9.2.1]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

I downloaded app and need to use it for some research. I works for others, not for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeout errors are typically an error not caused by your application itself - it's a problem with the connection to the SQL database.

If you are working on the DB locally, then you can check the timeout settings and modify them in order to cope with the delay in the request calls.

If you are working on a remote DB m/c, then maintaining a consistent Connection is needed. If you are unsure about how to keep the connection consistent with your machine to the DB machine, then write a simple batch script which pings the DB server and keeps the Connection alive for your application to send a request.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me to focus on database and I found out that my database, even when I created it with pgAdmin wasn't there when checking via psql in the terminal. So I created it manually. Thanks again!

Comment: Should have posted the link, instead of copying original answer: https://coderanch.com/t/428217/java/java-sql-SQLException-attempt-client